# Using db40 .db file in another pc

Tags: database, db4o

I am new to db4o. We are working on a team project in java using db4o and have inserted some objects in the database (say Cricketdb) on one pc. When I try copying the .db file and use it on my pc, it shows null values for the objects(that is the default values for the classes).

How can I import the database?
or
Is it not possible to do so?

This is my code block for the above :

```
public static void activateConnection(){
     db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(Db4oEmbedded
            .newConfiguration(), "Cricketdb");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy both the database file and your classes.

The most likely cause for this is that db4o is not being able to find your classes. Make sure your classes are in the in the classpath.